# Using map to replace elements of a list with (x-y)*(x-y), where y is the initial element

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

I have a bit of homework to do and I am a complete newbie to Haskell. The question I am having trouble with is to write a function which when given an integer `x` and a list of integers apply `(x-y)*(x-y)` to each element in the list and output the new list, with `y` being each element of the input list.

I have a very rough idea I will have to use the `map` function but I'm unsure how to go about it.

I have been looking at examples for squaring each element in a list and kind of understand how that works, but how I would implement the `(x-y)*(x-y)` with `y` being the current element completely baffles me.

```
squares :: [Int] -> [Int]
squares (x:xs) = x * x : squares xs
squares [] = []
```

the exact question I have been set is,

> Write a function `rela` which takes as arguments an integer `x` and a list of integers. It returns a similar list, but where each element `y` has been replaced by `(x-y)*(x-y)`, e.g.
>
> ```
> Main> rela 2 [3,5,7]
> [1,9,25]
> ```

---

I have managed to get it working after reading through some books, but the code I have made misses out the first element in the list. Any explanation why?

```
equation1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
equation1 x y = (x-y)*(x-y)
rela :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rela x [] =[]
rela x (y:ys) = [ equation1 x y | y <- ys ]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you should probably create a separate function that does what you want.

e.g.

```
f x y = (x-y)*(x-y)
```

Now, every time you create a function in Haskell with multiple parameters, it actually "curries" the function, which means that you get a new function when you apply the first argument to it.

So, you would get a new function by doing this

```
g = f 5
```

The expression `f 5` is actually a function

And you can apply a number to 'g' and x will always be '5'

So if we want to create a function that takes two parameters, 'x' and 'y', and applies `(x-y)*(x-y)` to a list where y is the current element, then all we need to do is the following:

```
f x y = (x-y)*(x-y)
squareDifference x = map (f x) [1,2,3,4]
```

Which you can use by calling `squareDifference 5` or any other number as an argument

A more general version would allow you to pass in a list as well

```
squareDifference x xs = map (f x) xs
```

Which you would call by doing `squareDifference 3 [1,2,3]`

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly but after a few attempts i am still stumped. am I on the right track by using this?                    rela :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
f x y = (x-y)*(x-y)

Comment: @blaneclorley: What you want to do is to write a function `map`, that gets a function `f :: a → b` as a parameter and applies it to all elements of the list, so that `map f [x₀, x₁, x₂, x₃ ..] ≡ [f x₀, f x₁, f x₂, f x₃ ..]`. Then you just create partially applied function (see above) and call `map` with it. The type signature of `rela` corresponds to `concatMap` and that's not really what you need in this case.

Comment: Still lost, If i am being brutally honest i need telling in layman's terms, I have only ever done a little bit of programming and that was years ago. I thought map was predefined? if i have to create my own map function how would i make it get the function?

Comment: @blaneclorley: You already have `f x y = (x - y)^2`, which is a function of type (for simplicity) `Int → Int → Int`, `map` expects a function of type `a → b` for some `a` and `b`, a list of values of type `a` (i.e. `[a]`) and returns a list of `b`s. Since you start with `[Int]` and want to end up with `[Int]` too, you have to provide a function `Int → Int`. If you apply only one argument to `f` (such as `f 5`), you get a function `Int → Int` with the first argument fixed (in this example to 5).

Comment: yes that help cheers, just picked through it. Just edited my question to show you the actual question i have been set

Comment: The key point to remember is that in Haskell functions can take functions as their parameter, and functions can return functions. Whenever you apply fewer parameters to a function than its type specifies you get a function as the return value. e.g. `squareDifference 10 :: Num b => [b] -> [b]`

Answer (score 10):

do you understand lambda functions?

```
map (\val -> the function) xs
```

is what you need.

currying is even better, but not as simple.

edit:

more conceptual...

map iterates down a list applying a function.

```
map (+ 3) xs
```

uses the currying technique mentioned above. you could also:

```
map (\x -> x + 3) xs
```

to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: nope sorry that doesn't make sense to me, I've been trying to work out how to write a function called rela which takes as arguments an integer x and a list of integers. It returns a similar list, but where each element y has been replaced by (x-y)*(x-y), and when rela 2 [3,5,7] is entered into the terminal returns the new list [1,9,25]. I've got close using the help given above but cannot get it to work, can you help?

Comment: wait into the terminal or into ghci?

Comment: few... 
you would have code
`repa x xs = map (lambda function) xs`

Comment: I've just ran f x y = (x-y)*(x-y)
repa x xs = map (f) xs and that hasn't worked could i be so cheeky to ask you for the complete answer to the question above and talk me through it? just my lecturer is away all week and the assignments due mid week and i have other questions to do and this is the basis

Comment: or point me to a good tutorial for dummy newbie programmers for haskell?

Answer (score 2):

Simple example:

```
rela :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rela x = map (\y -> (x-y)*(x-y))
```

Or might you want any perversions? -) Here you are with Applicatives:

```
import Control.Applicative
rela :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rela x = map $ (*) <$> (x-) <*> (x-)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I guess you mean this:

```
Prelude> let rela n = map (\ x -> (x - n)^2)
Prelude> rela 2  [3,5,7] 
[1,9,25]
```